# XPath: Get parent node from child node

Tags: xml, xpath

I need get the parent node for child node `title 50`

At the moment I am using only

```
//*[title="50"]
```

How could I get its parent?
Result should be the `store` node.

---

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<d:data xmlns:d="defiant-namespace" d:mi="23">
    <store d:mi="22">
        <book price="12.99" d:price="Number" d:mi="4">
            <title d:constr="String" d:mi="1">Sword of Honour</title>
            <category d:constr="String" d:mi="2">fiction</category>
            <author d:constr="String" d:mi="3">Evelyn Waugh</author>
        </book>
        <book price="8.99" d:price="Number" d:mi="9">
            <title d:constr="String" d:mi="5">Moby Dick</title>
            <category d:constr="String" d:mi="6">fiction</category>
            <author d:constr="String" d:mi="7">Herman Melville</author>
            <isbn d:constr="String" d:mi="8">0-553-21311-3</isbn>
        </book>
        <book price="8.95" d:price="Number" d:mi="13">
            <title d:constr="String" d:mi="10">50</title>
            <category d:constr="String" d:mi="11">reference</category>
            <author d:constr="String" d:mi="12">Nigel Rees</author>
        </book>
        <book price="22.99" d:price="Number" d:mi="18">
            <title d:constr="String" d:mi="14">The Lord of the Rings</title>
            <category d:constr="String" d:mi="15">fiction</category>
            <author d:constr="String" d:mi="16">J. R. R. Tolkien</author>
            <isbn d:constr="String" d:mi="17">0-395-19395-8</isbn>
        </book>
        <bicycle price="19.95" d:price="Number" d:mi="21">
            <brand d:constr="String" d:mi="19">Cannondale</brand>
            <color d:constr="String" d:mi="20">red</color>
        </bicycle>
    </store>
</d:data>
```

Comment: `XPATH/..`  or `XPATH/parent::*` will select the parent nodes of the nodes selected by XPATH, but often it is better to simply select the parent directly without descending first to its child.  See how [below](https://stackoverflow.com/a/58065057/290085).

Answer (score 476, accepted):

Use the [`parent` axes](https://www.w3schools.com/xml/xpath_axes.asp) with the parent node's name.

```
//*[title="50"]/parent::store
```

This XPath will only select the parent node if it is a `store`.

But you can also use one of these

```
//*[title="50"]/parent::*
//*[title="50"]/..
```

These xpaths will select any parent node. So if the document changes you will always select a node, even if it is not the node you expect.

**EDIT**

> What happens in the given example where the parent is a bicycle but the parent of the parent is a store?
>
> Does it ascent?

No, it only selects the store if it is a parent of the node that matches `//*[title="50"]`.

> If not, is there a method to ascent in such cases and return None if there is no such parent?

Yes, you can use `ancestor` axes

```
//*[title="50"]/ancestor::store
```

This will select all ancestors of the node matching `//*[title="50"]` that are ` stores. E.g.

```
<data xmlns:d="defiant-namespace" d:mi="23">
    <store mi="1">
        <store mi="22">
            <book price="8.95" d:price="Number" d:mi="13">
                <title d:constr="String" d:mi="10">50</title>
                <category d:constr="String" d:mi="11">reference</category>
                <author d:constr="String" d:mi="12">Nigel Rees</author>
            </book>
        </store>
    </store>
</data>
```

[image: XPath selection result]

Comment: You could also use the `parent::*` abbreviated syntax `..` (example: `//*[title="50"]/..`) or a nested predicate (example: `//*[*[title="50"]]`)

Comment: Additional info: http://www.w3.org/TR/xpath/#axes and http://www.w3.org/TR/xpath/#path-abbrev

Comment: Or `parent::node()` which corresponds to the shortcut `..` and is better in my opinion. In fact `parent::*` is limited to the principal node type of the axis which in most cases is not a problem.

Comment: If you are using try `.xpath('..')` or `xpath('parent::node()')`

Comment: "This XPath will only select the parent node if it is a store." - and what happens in the given example where the parent is `bicycle` but the parent of the parent is `store`? Does it ascent? If not, is there a method to ascent in such cases and return `None` if there is no such parent?

Comment: what a well written super helpful answer: i can directly use `ancestor::` to solve my task

Comment: For the life of me I couldn't select the Store element if it is the root element unless I put it inside another container. I'd have thought /[field='value'] would get it (if i put inside a container root then /Store[field='value'] works. iow <Store><field>value</field></Store doesn't get found with /[field='value'] but <anything><Store><field>value</field></Store></anything> then works with /Store[field='value']. Here is what finally worked for me with Store as root: /*/..[field='value']

Answer (score 50):

Just as an alternative, you can use `ancestor`.

```
//*[title="50"]/ancestor::store
```

It's more powerful than `parent` since it can get even the grandparent or great great grandparent

Comment: It is not "more powerful". It is just different. Thus the choice of the axis depends on the use case.

Comment: No, it's just wrong. Judging from op's xpath he asked for a parent, not ancestor.

Comment: It's wrong but helpful, as many people might search for "parent" when they really mean "any parent". I think it is an adequate answer.

Answer (score 24):

<sup>***New, improved answer to an old, frequently asked question...***</sup>

> How could I get its parent? Result should be the `store` node.

### Use a predicate rather than the `parent::` or `ancestor::` axis

Most answers here select the `title` and then traverse up to the targeted parent or ancestor (`store`) element.  A simpler, direct approach is to select parent or ancestor element directly in the first place, obviating the need to traverse to a `parent::` or `ancestor::` axes:

```
//*[book/title = "50"]
```

Should the intervening elements vary in name:

```
//*[*/title = "50"]
```

Or, in name and depth:

```
//*[.//title = "50"]
```

Answer (score 19):

You can use the two dots at the end of expression, too. See this example:

```
//*[title="50"]/..
```

Answer (score 2):

```
//store[book[title[text()="50"]]]
```

or

```
//store[*[title[text()="50"]]]
```

Comment: Why do you prefer this over the other options? And especially the accepted answer, which includes a lengthy explanation, and has been validated by 450 members of the community? Please [edit] your answer to help explain the benefits of this approach, and especially compared to previously established proposals.