# Nodelist with values and parent's attribute as names

Tags: xml, xpath, jenkins

I'm new to XML files and am trying to get out some values using XPath. I will plot this values in Jenkins using the [Plot plugin](https://wiki.jenkins-ci.org/display/JENKINS/Plot+Plugin). This takes the element names on the x-axis and the element value on the y-axis.

My xml file looks like:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" ?>
<foo>
    <file file_name="file1.c">
        <metrics>
            <metric id="M1">15</metric>
            <metric id="M2">7</metric>
            <metric id="M3">9</metric>
        </metrics>
    </file>
    <file file_name="file2.c">
        <metrics>
            <metric id="M1">1110</metric>
            <metric id="M2">56</metric>
            <metric id="M3">1</metric>
        </metrics>
    </file>
</foo>
```

I want to plot `M1` for all `file_name`, therefore what I need to get back using XPath is a `nodelist` like

```
<file1.c>15</file1.c>
<file2.c>1110</file1.c>
```

I tried

```
//file/metrics/*[@id='M1']
```

but so I get

```
<metric id="M1">15</metric>
<metric id="M1">15</metric>
```

I found some similar questions, but couldn't adapt it to my case:
[This](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28237694/xpath-get-parent-node-from-child) for example gets back the parent element including all children.

How can I achieve what I need?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

XPath can't create new elements on its own. You have to use XQuery or an XSLT transformation or a home-made parsing using a combination of DOM and XPath in the language of your choice. XPath 2.0 could be of some help but I guess you're limited to XPath 1.0.

BTW I would add some context to your XPath expression instead of using `*` :

```
//file/metrics/metric[@id='M1']
```

With XPath 2.0 alone, you could do this :

```
string-join(//file/(@file_name,metrics/metric[@id='M1']/text()),',')
```

And get a string with the data you need :

```
file1.c,15,file2.c,1110
```

It is more powerful than XPath 1.

With XQuery 1.0, you could write :

```
<document_element>
{
  for $f in //file
  return element { $f/@file_name } { $f/metrics/metric[@id='M1']/text() }
}
</document_element>
```

And get the answer you want :

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<document_element>
   <file1.c>15</file1.c>
   <file2.c>1110</file2.c>
</document_element>
```

We use a computed element constructor `element { ... } { ... }`to dynamically create a new element whose name is based on some value in the file. XQuery is really powerful and convenient to use.

Comment: Thank you, using XQuery would work for sure. Since I have no experience with that I prefered to export this file in csv (instead of xml), edit it and plot the data from the resulting file.

Comment: Thank you for the edit. Unfortunately I'm limited to XPath 1.

Comment: I have tested the solution using XQuery and it works well. For all those who aren't familiar with XQuery this is how I did it: first I installed [xmlsh](http://www.xmlsh.org/HomePage), then I saved the code proposed by Ikuty as `create_report.xquery`
Then run `xmlsh` and `xquery -i my_file.xml -f create_report.xquery > report.xml` from command line, where `my_file.xml` is my initial file and `report.xml` will be the output file.

Comment: Didn't know about `xmlsh`. It is interesting