# Select parent of specific node using xpath/python

Tags: python, xpath

How do I get the href value for the a in this snippet of html?

I need to get it based on that class in i tag

```
<!--
<a href="https://link.com" target="_blank"><i class="foobar"></i>  </a>           
-->
```

I tried this, but am getting no results

```
foo_links = tree.xpath('//a[i/@class="foobar"]')
```

Answer (score 1):

Your code does work for me — it returns a list of `<a>`. If you want a list of `href`s not the element itself, add `/@href`:

```
hrefs = tree.xpath('//a[i/@class="foobar"]/@href')
```

You could also first find the `<i>`s, then use [`/parent::*`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28237694/xpath-get-parent-node-from-child) (or simply `/..`) to get back to the `<a>`s.

```
hrefs = tree.xpath('//a/i[@class="foobar"]/../@href')
#                     ^                    ^  ^
#                     |                    |  obtain the 'href'
#                     |                    |
#                     |                    get the parent of the <i>
#                     |
#                     find all <i class="foobar"> contained in an <a>.
```

If all of these don't work, you may want to verify if the structure of the document is correct.

Note that XPath won't peek inside comments `<!-- -->`. If the `<a>` is indeed inside the comments `<!-- -->`, you need to manually extract the document out first.

```
hrefs = [href for comment in tree.xpath('//comment()') 
              # find all comments
              for href in lxml.html.fromstring(comment.text)
              # parse content of comment as a new HTML file
                              .xpath('//a[i/@class="foobar"]/@href')
                              # read those hrefs.
]
```

Comment: Just curious why not just `//a/@href` ?

Comment: @svasa OP said "*I need to get it based on that class in i tag*"

Comment: Ok didn't see. got it.

Answer (score 0):

You should note that target element is `HTML` *comment*. You cannot simply get `<a>` from *comment* with `XPath` like `"//a"` as in this case it's not a node, but simple string.

Try  below code:

```
import re

foo_links = tree.xpath('//comment()') # get list of all comments on page
for link in foo_links:
    if '<i class="foobar">' in link.text:
        href = re.search('\w+://\w+.\w+', link.text).group(0) # get href value from required comment
        break
```

P.S. You might need to use more complex regular expression to match link `URL`

Comment: This seems to be working the best. The comments/<!-- is mucking things up. 

I did add an extra .\w+ to get the rest of the URL. For some reason I'm only getting one record at a time, and a different one each time I run it. Probably some issue with me appending to the list I'm creating. Thanks

Comment: Removed the `break` and i'm getting what I was after