# How select a parent node with XPath?

Tags: html, xml, xpath

If I have

```
<div>
  <a>
    <table>
      <tr>
        <td value="val">
```

If I want to select the a containing a `td` with `value="val"`, how can I do that?

I have tested:

```
//td[@value="val"]
```

But I obtain the td node, I want to obtain the `a` node. How can I achieve that with XPath?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [XPath: Get parent node from child node](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28237694/xpath-get-parent-node-from-child-node)

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You can use either of the below options.

```
//td[@value="val"]/ancestor::a
^
td with value val
                   ^
                    ancestor link
```

or

Preferred xpath in this case

```
//a[.//td[@value="val"]]
^
Get me any link which have td with value as val.
```

or

The below xpath works now, but when there any change to the page eg: if table is moved into a div, then this xpath will break.

```
//td[@value="val"]/parent::tr/parent::table/parent::a
```

Personally I prefer the 2nd option atleast in this case as `a` does not have any specific properties. And `ancestor::a` will select any link which is ancestor of the td.

Answer (score 3):

The direct answer to your question about how to select a parent in XPath is to use the `parent::` axis or the `..` abbreviation.  However, often, as in your case, you can select the targeted "parent" directly via a predicate on a descendant rather than selecting the descendant and then having to traverse back up to the parent.   For example, ...

This XPath,

```
//a[.//td/@value = "val"]
```

will select all `a` elements with a `td` descendant with a `@value` attribute value equal to `"val"`.

---

**Update:** I wasn't paying attention and now see that @suppurtui already provided the above XPath as an option.  I'll leave this up for any benefit provided by my explanation, but please upvote [@supputuri's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/58063004/290085) (as I have just done).  Thanks.