# How to find the parent element knowing the child

Tags: c#, selenium

I found a child by text in the following way.

```
Driver.FindElement(By.XPath("//span[contains(@class,'MyClass')][contains(text(),'MyText')]"));
```

The problem is that I need to click on the parent element. The element on the page appears dynamically and for earlier I only know the text. Is it possible to program this?

My html:

```html
<div class="list-item list-item-station ui-draggable ui-draggable-handle">
    <div class="operations">
        <span class="fa fa-times"></span>
    </div>
    <div class="icon-image image-item">
        <span class="fa fa-user"></span>
    </div>
    <div class="icon-name editable-input-long">
        <span class="will-edit will-edit-input will-edit-textarea">MyText</span><textarea class="editable-  textarea"></textarea>
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: hi,
maybe this is helpful: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28237694/xpath-get-parent-node-from-child-node

Comment: Share HTML with parent element please

Comment: A user is created in the browser interface. Then he appears among others. It is necessary to choose it. I know the login under which it is created. Therefore, xpath is always different. I can contact directly by name as above. But you need to click on the parent element to open another page with its rights.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [XPath: Get parent node from child node](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28237694/xpath-get-parent-node-from-child-node)

Answer (score 1):

I'm using XPath:

```
    using (IWebDriver driver = new ChromeDriver(this.SeleniumDriverPath, driveroptions))
                {
                    try
                    {
                        driver.Navigate().GoToUrl("http://www.google.com/");

                        IWebElement query = driver.FindElement(By.Name("q"));
            query.SendKeys("link");
                    query.Submit();

                        var wait = new WebDriverWait(driver, TimeSpan.FromSeconds(10));
                        var listElement = driver.FindElements(OpenQA.Selenium.By.XPath(".//*[@id='search']//div[@class='g']"));
                        foreach( var e in listElement)
                        {
                                    // parent element:
                            var parent = e.FindElement(OpenQA.Selenium.By.XPath("./.."));   //parent element
    parent.Click();
                        }
                    }
                    catch(Exception ex)
                    {
                        ...
                    }

                    driver.Quit();
                }
```

Answer (score 0):

With XPath you can do DOM navigation so you can start by grabbing the `IWebElement` that is the child and then use an XPath of `..` to navigate up one level.

```
IWebElement child = Driver.FindElement(By.XPath("//span[contains(@class,'MyClass')][contains(text(),'MyText')]"));
child.FindElement(By.XPath("..")).Click();
```

If you are able to modify your child XPath, you can just find the parent in one lookup.

```
Driver.FindElement(By.XPath("//span[contains(@class,'MyClass')][contains(text(),'MyText')]/..")).Click();
                                                                                          ^ added the parent axis here
```

There are other ways to accomplish this but these two methods should get you started.

Reference:
[MDN Web docs - parent](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/XPath/Axes/parent)

Answer (score 0):

You can get parent `list-item` div with xpath below:

```
Driver.FindElement(By.XPath("//span[contains(@class,'will-edit')][contains(text(),'MyText')]/ancestor::div[contains(@class,'list-item')][1]"));
```

To get `list-item` div with child span with **MyText**:

```
Driver.FindElement(By.XPath("//div[contains(@class,'list-item') and .//span[contains(@class,'will-edit')][contains(text(),'MyText')]]"));
```

Get textarea using span with **MyText**:

```
Driver.FindElement(By.XPath("//div[contains(@class,'list-item') and .//span[contains(@class,'will-edit')][contains(text(),'MyText')]]//textarea"));
```

Answer (score 0):

JeffC's answer came up to me. Thank you very much. I redid the code a bit to fit my situation.

```html
IWebElement child = Browser.FindElement(By.XPath("//span[contains(@class,'will-edit will-edit-input will-edit-textarea')][contains(text(),'"+name+"')]"));
child.FindElement(By.XPath("../..")).Click();
```

I think other answers may come up. I did not try. Thank you all very much!