# how to get only label text not span text in selenium python?

Tags: python-3.x, selenium, xpath

Here is the html

```
<label>Hello <span class="">Span text here</span></label>
```

Any Help would be appreciated & thanks in Advance

Comment: See if this helps https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28237694/xpath-get-parent-node-from-child-node.

Comment: @AkshatRaj i find out the solution to get the label text only not span thanks for the response

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This `xpath` matches only text from parent tag:

```
//label/text()
```