# How can i extract what is on the second <td>, CAT5 is what I need to extract in to a xpath

Tags: xpath, xpath-2.0, xpath-1.0

```
<table class="">
 <tbody class>
   <tr class>
   <tr class>
   <tr class>
     <td>
      <span>Series</span>
     <td>CAT5</td>
```

The number of tr and td can be different because there are multiples tables and I needed it in a xpath format like this:

```
//table[@class="info-table specifications-table"]/tbody/tr/td/span[contains(text(),'Series')]/....
```

I tried like this but the tr order is different each time, the only constant is the value is always on the Series row in the table

```
//table[@class="info-table specifications-table"]/tbody/tr[8]/td[2]
```

[Table looks like this and the Series can be on different position from top to bottom](https://i.stack.imgur.com/2O4rj.png)

Comment: What did you try? And what didn't work?

Comment: This what I tried but is not working because the td is not a sibling of the span `//table[@class="info-table specifications-table"]/tbody/tr/td/span[contains(text(),'Series')]/following-sibling::td`

Comment: add a [parent selector then?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28237694/xpath-get-parent-node-from-child-node) Maybe something like `//table[@class="info-table specifications-table"]/tbody/tr/td/span[contains(text(),'Series')]/parent::td/following-sibling::td`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can either use [textContent](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Node/textContent) (or [innerHTML](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element/innerHTML)) to get the desired result:

The xpath for solving this is using [parent selector like described here:](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28237694/xpath-get-parent-node-from-child-node)

`//table[@class="info-table specifications-table"]/tbody/tr/td/span[contains(text(),'Series')]/parent::td/following-sibling::td`

```js
document.querySelectorAll('tr td:nth-child(2)').forEach(td => console.log(td.textContent))
```

```html
<table class="">
  <tbody class>
    <tr class>
      <td>
        <span>Series</span>
      </td>
      <td>CAT5</td>
    </tr>
    <tr class>
      <td>
        <span>Series</span>
      </td>
      <td>CAT1</td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>
```

Comment: I need the xpath so something like this: //table[@class="info-table specifications-table"]/tbody/tr/td/span[contains(text(),'Series')]/....

Comment: That's a totally different thing than what you posted in your question. Please update your question with all info that we need.